# PHP 7+ custom salt hashing algorithm

Tags: hash, php

I'd like to hash email addresses with the same salt to make the hash searchable\indexable and make it hard to figure out the actual data. I wanted to use `bcrypt`, but I found that from PHP 7 custom salt is not supported by the `password_hash()` function.

Is there any alternative way that supports custom salt or pepper only and which is cryptographically secure compared to checksums?

Comment: 1) Using salt more than once you eliminate the purpose of the salt. If you use the same salt for all data, it is the same, as not to use any salt at all.

Comment: 2) Why do you need hash to be cryptographically secure?

Comment: @mentallurg I need only pepper here, but with a relative good algorithm. I want to keep the data searcheable relative fast, because it is an index and I don't want to write a custom encrypted indexing method.

Comment: Just concatenate your salt onto the email address? (also, when the salt is always the same, it's called a pepper)

Comment: The proper way is following. 1) If email needs protection, it should not be used as user ID for login purposes. Instead, user should pickup some user ID. Then you can encrypt email e.g. using a TPM. 2) If email does not need protection, then you can use it for login.

Comment: Do you want a salt, or are you just wanting the output to be the same and not using a salt would also meet your requirements? Why do you need this "searchable" hash to be "cryptographically secure"?

Comment: Ultimately, the question "what PHP hash allows for a custom salt?" is not a security question but a pure programming question (and one that's easy to look up). If you are wanting a security answer, you will have to answer the security context questions we've asked.

Comment: @mentallurg Good point. I would accept it as an answer.

Comment: @schroeder I asked it on SO, but I did not get a decent answer there. So I thought maybe it is too security related. Not entirely a programming question, because there can be many implementations of bcrypt and some of them can be better than others from security perspective...

Comment: But you never defined what the security perspective was ...

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose fulfilled by this desire? What is your threat model? It sounds like you don't have a good idea how much to be concerned about your various risks, or how viable the various threats are.

Email addresses are generally not secret information. Indeed, they're usually what you use to look up the salt. If you just want to check whether a given email address has been entered before without having them in plain text, any secure hashing algorithm will do, with a fixed salt if you want to make looking up the hash elsewhere also not work. There's no need for an expensive password-hashing algorithm (and indeed, it's a DoS risk to use one) with something like this; you can't meaningfully prevent brute-forcing. You couldn't even if random unique salts were possible - the search space simply isn't big enough - but you definitely can't if you want fast lookup.

Comment: I want to add some protection against database theft, so I encrypt personal data. Since email addresses are identifiers I want to have a repeatable hashing or encryption mechanism, so I can find them with a simple SQL SELECT instead of going through the whole users table by each login which would make the system DDoS vulnerable. It doesn't have to be perfect, but better than plain text or a checksum algorithm.

Comment: If the email addresses are _user account_ identifiers, aren't you going to need them at various points (to send emails to the users)? If not, and they're _just_ PII, why not ask the user for a username instead of an email address?

Comment: I'll use the encrypted version for email sending and the hashed version for identifying. I don't want to have an username in this application.

Comment: "I don't want to have an username in this application" -- but your hash becomes the username. I'm not sure that you have worked out all the details here. And the emails are still there and accessible with the key. I don't think you've quite worked out all the details and security/data protection issues here.

Comment: Storing both the encrypted and the hashed version of the data is strictly less secure than only storing one; an attacker can not only try both avenues of attack (steal the key to decrypt the ciphertext/catch the decrypted version in memory, and brute-force hashes), the two types of data aid each other (depending on the cipher used, the attacker can use length and possibly consistent blocks of ciphertext to narrow the brute-force candidates for a hash, and once a given hash is brute-forced, potentially derive information about other ciphertexts). Just use encryption only, if you use it at all.

Answer (score -2):

Never mind I found that I can use the [crypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function with blowfish to do it. Checking it this way is sensitive to timing attacks though. I made it relative timing attack safe with usleep and microtime by measuring the duration and adjusting it to minimum 200 msecs with 100 msecs steps. For my current purpose this is good enough.

The other solution would be writing a custom encrypted indexing solution for email addresses and/or using an encrypted caching mechanisms so I would not need to check all email addresses each time I want to identify the users. I think for this project it would be too much effort to do so.

Comment: It make no sense to talk about timing attacks, because you have much bigger problem - you use the same salt for all data.

Comment: @mentallurg You miss the point, this is not password encryption and I don't want to hash.verify all email addresses in the database just to figure out which one is the right. Security is not about maximum security it is about good enough security.

Comment: You seem to not understand the purpose of salt. Salt has nothing to do with passwords. The purpose of salt is to prevent rainbow tables, no matter what is the process of transformations/hashes it has. If you use the same salt everywhere, this allows usage of rainbow tables. That's why the security in your case is absolutely the same as without salt. Adding salt in the way you described makes your computation process more complex without adding any little security. The effort to find out hashed emails is absolutely the same as in case without salt. So why do use salt at all?

Comment: Why are you looking for password hash options? Why won't MD5 work, for instance? Why are timing attacks relevant? I find the question, the context, your requirements, and this potentially acceptable solution very confusing. You really need to clear up all this.

Comment: The fact that not one, but **several** people, who are well-versed in security, are telling you that your scheme makes **no sense at all**, should be an indicator that you are doing it wrong. Take CBHacking's advice, make a threat model and most importantly, learn what these security measures are designed to mitigate.